# Selenium action click repeats previous calls

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
var action = new Actions(driver);
var body = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//body"));
action.MoveToElement(body, x, y).Click().Build().Perform();
action.MoveToElement(body, secondx, secondy).Click().Build().Perform();
```

So I want my to at first click on element based on `x` and `y` coordinates and then click on `secondx` and `secondy`. But what I get is:

1 step: it clicks on `x` and `y`

2 step: it clicks on `x` and `y`

3 step: it clicks on `secondx` and `secondy`

I solved that by calling `action = new Actions(driver);` so it created new object and then clicks but isn't there any better way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

In your example the actions are stacked in a single instance (`action`). Since `Perform` doesn't remove the actions already preformed, the second call on `Perform` also executes the actions from the first `Perform`.

To overcome this issue, either create two instances:

```
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(body, x, y).Click().Perform();
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(body, secondx, secondy).Click().Perform();
```

Or call `Perform` only once:

```
new Actions(driver)
  .MoveToElement(body, x, y)
  .Click()
  .MoveToElement(body, secondx, secondy)
  .Click()
  .Perform();
```